# Firebase doesn't send emails after deploying + no logs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I implemented the code below and it works perfectly fine when I run it in on local machine with `npm start`

However, when I deploy it on Firebase, the sendOrderEmail function doesn't work.

I don't even get any logs.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const {email, password} = require('./config');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const htmlToText = require('nodemailer-html-to-text').htmlToText;

admin.initializeApp();

const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: email,
        pass: password
    }
});

mailTransport.use("compile", htmlToText());

const APP_NAME = 'the.Travelest';

exports.sendUserEmail = functions.database
    .ref("/lettersRequest/{pushId}")
    .onCreate(request => {
        return sendOrderEmail(request.val().email);
    });

async function sendOrderEmail(email){
        const mailOptions = {
            from: `${APP_NAME}`,
            to: email,
            subject: `Your order from ${APP_NAME}`,
            html: `
                <div>
                    <strong> Hello </strong>
                    World
                </div>
            `
        };
        return await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    }
```

UPDATE
After checking the logic, I believe that I've found the issues in another place.

So, the logic is - when I click on SUBMIT in form, I send the data to Firebase Runtime Database. And this action triggers the function above and send the email.

However, the SUBMIT button doesn't trigger the process it should trigger. I don't see even `console.log` result in the console, when I click on SUBMIT
Again, it works locally, when I run `nom start`

Here is the submit handler:

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        setErrors(validate(values))
        setIsSubmitting(true)

        try{
            const newRequestRef = database.ref('lettersRequest').push();
            const newRequest = {
                country: values.country,
                travelersAmount: values.travelersAmount,
                introExtro: values.introExtro,
                comments: values.comments,
                email: values.email,
                phone: values.phone
            };
            newRequestRef.set({
                email: values.email,
                request: newRequest
            });
            console.log("no error")
        }catch(e){
            console.log("error")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(email, password)` in the function just to make sure the credentials are correct? Also try adding a log statement inside of the function. Also are you adding data to right path in database to trigger the function?

Comment: Hi Dharmaraj, everything what you've mentioned works and provides correct results, when I check it locally.. And, in opposite, when I try to get these results after deployment, I don't get any. Looks like the function is not called,  but I have no idea, why

Comment: Can you confirm you are adding data to write path to trigger the db? Also the `onCreate` takes 2 parameters can you try adding both just to confirm? `.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {...}`

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes, the path is correct and it works perfectly, when I check it locally.. I've added second parameter to ```onCreate()``` , but it didn't change anything:(

Comment: That's wierd. Can you confirm the function is actually deployed ? There will be logs of that. Can you share those ?

Comment: sure, the function wouldn't work locally without deployment. However, I deployed it again:

Comment: "the function wouldn't work locally without deployment." That's a confusing statement. Just to clarify, it works using emulators?

Comment: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"someemail@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/PROJECT_NAME/locations/us-central1/functions/sendUserEmail"}

Comment: It works when I run ```npm start```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was even more trivial than I could expect :D
I did deploy to firebase, but I've never did commit and build project...
As a result, nothing was updated after each deploy.

Stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the promise returned by `set()`. Try this:

```js
const handleSubmit = event => {
event.preventDefault();

  setErrors(validate(values))
  setIsSubmitting(true)

  const newRequestRef = database.ref('lettersRequest').push();
  const newRequest = {
    country: values.country,
    travelersAmount: values.travelersAmount,
    introExtro: values.introExtro,
    comments: values.comments,
    email: values.email,
    phone: values.phone
  };
  newRequestRef.set({
    email: values.email,
    request: newRequest
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("Request Added in Database")
  }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

If it logs 'Request Added in Database' then it has been added successfully and your function should trigger.

Additionally, this can also be done by a [Callable Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) which means you call the function directly from the client, do all the validation, add the data in database and send the email instead of using database triggers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get nothing in console.. Even if I just add ```console.log("!")``` right after/before ```event.preventDefault()```

Comment: @KonstantinAron then it seems your button is not working properly. Can you share your HTML as well ?

Comment: The issue is that it does - the lines ```event.preventDefault();``` and ```setIsSubmitting(true)``` work properly. The part with handleSubmit: ```<Form action="#" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>```

Comment: @KonstantinAron is the data being added in database? No error is logged either?

Comment: If I run ```npm start```, yes, everything works perfectly, data goes to database

Comment: @KonstantinAron `npm start` in Cloud functions? How does that relate to this button click? I'm asking if the data is added when you click the button?

Comment: So, I have 2 scenarios - when I run program locally with ```npm start``` and when I run the deployed version. When I run it locally, button works and data goes to the database. When I run the deployed version, button works partially - it changes the value of ```setIsSubmitting```, but doesn't send the data to database